# Busy Spin in Java: Prevent Compiler/JIT optimization

Tags: java, optimization, jvm, jit

I am trying to perform busy spins in a Java program, and want to prevent the compiler or JIT from optimizing away the code. The code is a simple loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < spins; i++) {
}
```

where spins is the input.

How can I prevent this piece of code from being optimized away?

Comment: If `spin` was declared as `volatile` that might be sufficient.  But check the native code emitted by the JIT compiler.  Another way would be to do a useless calculation in the loop and assign the result to a field.

Comment: Perhaps [Thread.onSpinWait()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#onSpinWait())?

Comment: does this solve your issue? https://eclipse.dev/openj9/docs/jit/

Comment: onSpinWait() seems to work. @VGR please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.onSpinWait()` is made for this very purpose.  The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#onSpinWait()) even shows an example:

```
volatile boolean eventNotificationNotReceived;

void waitForEventAndHandleIt() {
    while (eventNotificationNotReceived) {
        Thread.onSpinWait();
    }
    readAndProcessEvent();
}
```